# nodejs: worker disconnect() not working as expected

Tags: node.js, multithreading

I am trying to disconnect worker from cluster when there is a request to route "/disconnect". Worker is not getting disconnected even though master is receiving the disconnect event from worker.

**Worker**

```
var express=require("express"),
app=express(),
http=require("http"),
server = null;

app.get('/disconnect',function(req,res){
  var worker = require('cluster').worker;    
  setTimeout(function(){        
    // disconnect from the cluster            
    if(worker) worker.disconnect();                
   }, 2000);
  res.send("Worker " +   worker.id +  " is disconnecting ");
});

server = http.createServer(app).listen(3000);

server.on('close', function() {
   console.log("server asked to close");
});
```

**LOG**

```
> node app/app_cluster.js

CLUSTER: Worker 1 started
CLUSTER: Worker 2 started
CLUSTER: Worker 3 started
CLUSTER: Worker 4 started
Yay, the worker responded after it was forked
Yay, the worker responded after it was forked
Yay, the worker responded after it was forked
Yay, the worker responded after it was forked
A worker is now connected to null:3000
A worker is now connected to null:3000
A worker is now connected to null:3000
A worker is now connected to null:3000
CLUSTER: Worker 1 disconnected from the cluster.
events.js:85
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
        ^
Error: IPC channel is already disconnected
at process.target.disconnect (child_process.js:510:26)
at Worker.disconnect (cluster.js:650:13)
at null._onTimeout (/home/user/nodejs/node-hawkeye/app/app.js:18:31)
at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:110:15)
CLUSTER: Worker 1 died with exit code 1 (null)
```

I have two doubts here

1. For the first request to "/disconnect" route I see "CLUSTER: Worker 1 disconnected from the cluster." in the log. I wait for about 10 secs before sending request to "/disconnect" route again. When I send for the second time I got error "Error: IPC channel is already disconnected".
2. According to the documentation https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html#cluster_worker_disconnect

   ***In a worker, this function will close all servers, wait for the 'close' event on those servers, and then disconnect the IPC channel.***

   I am not seeing close event on the server in my worker code. Will worker call server.close() internally on worker.disconnect() ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first doubt got clarified. It took nearly two minutes to receive 'exit' event after 'disconnect' event in the Master. For my test case I waited for about 10 secs to send request to '/disconnect' route after the first request, seems 10 secs is not enough. Please see the below log where I captured time in the log for the events.

**Log**

```
> node app/app_cluster.js

CLUSTER: Worker 1 started
CLUSTER: Worker 2 started
CLUSTER: Worker 3 started
CLUSTER: Worker 4 started
Yay, the worker responded after it was forked
Yay, the worker responded after it was forked
Yay, the worker responded after it was forked
Yay, the worker responded after it was forked
A worker is now connected to null:3000
A worker is now connected to null:3000
A worker is now connected to null:3000
A worker is now connected to null:3000
CLUSTER: Worker 3 disconnected from the cluster.Tue Aug 11 2015    13:45:35 GMT+0530 (IST)
CLUSTER: Worker 3 died with exit code 0 (null)Tue Aug 11 2015 13:47:29 GMT+0530 (IST)
```

**UPDATE**

I am not sure whether 2 mins between 'disconnect' and 'exit' events is acceptable, but, it seems one check worker.isConnected() to know the status of IPC connection.

There is a warning in the doc https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html#cluster_cluster_workers

**A worker is removed from cluster.workers after the worker has disconnected and exited. The order between these two events cannot be determined in advance. However, it is guaranteed that the removal from the cluster.workers list happens before last 'disconnect' or 'exit' event is emitted.**

If this is the case I am not sure how to handle incoming requests if the IPC channel is dead and request came to disconnected worker.

Answer (score 0):

.disconnect() closes IPC (inter process communication) channel and server.close() closes server for any new inbound requests... these are closing different sides (one closing connection to master and other processes and other closing to outside).

Doing disconnect immediately on worker side, just disconnects it and does not give time to do close or anything...

If you look at example from docs,  you can see that it sends a message from master which, when received by worker, triggers disconnect and kill timer.

Comment: according to documentation  https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html#cluster_worker_disconnect "In a worker, this function will close all servers, wait for the 'close' event on those servers, and then disconnect the IPC channel."